# Counter Problems and Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) in C

Tags: c, linked-list, counter

I am currently coding in C and am having trouble trying to selectively search through a linked list of movie information/rating structs. So far I've just gotten a segmentation fault core dump. My current algorithm basically while loops current = current->next except until it reaches NULL in the linked list. It prints out the movie details (through show_structure()) if the user input matches the title information in the linked list.

But to be honest, I want to be able to solve this problem while also implementing where if the user types in a movie title that is not in the linked list it would print out: " Movie does not exist in the database."

Also somehow the counter doesn't increment when I update new movies into the linked list. It keeps staying at 1. Any ideas?

This is my code so far:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct movie_node {
    char title[250];
    int year;
    unsigned char rating;
    struct movie_node *next;
};

typedef struct movie_node movie_t;

movie_t *first;
movie_t *current;
movie_t *new;
movie_t *make_structure(void);

void fill_structure(movie_t *a); 
void show_structure(movie_t *a);


int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    char traverse = 1;
    char maininput[1];
    char searchinput[250];  
while (traverse)
{
    printf("%d Movie(s) in the database. Update, Search, or Quit (U/S/Q): ", counter);
    scanf("%1s", maininput);

    if (strcmp("U", maininput) == 0)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
            {
            first = make_structure();
            current = first;
            }               
        else
            {
            new = make_structure();
            current->next=new;
            current=new;
            }
        counter++;            //COUNTER DOESN'T INCREMENT
        fill_structure(current);
        current->next = NULL;
        printf("Movie %s is added to the database.\n\n", current->title);
    }
    if (strcmp("S", maininput) == 0)
    {

        printf("Name of the movie: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", searchinput);
        current = first;

        do
        { 
            current=current->next;
            if (strcmp(searchinput, current->title) == 0)  //PROBLEM LIES HERE
                {show_structure(current);}
        } while(current != NULL);
    }
    if (strcmp("Q", maininput) == 0)
    {
        traverse = 0;
    }           
}
return 0;
}

movie_t *make_structure(void)
    {
    movie_t *a;
    a = (movie_t *)malloc(sizeof(movie_t));
    return a;
    }

void fill_structure(movie_t *a)
    {
    printf("Name of the movie: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", a->title);
    printf("Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &a->year);
    printf("Rating: ");
    scanf("%hhu", &a->rating);
    }

void show_structure(movie_t *a)
    {
    printf("Year: %d ", a->year);
    printf("Rating: %hhu", a->rating);
    }
```

Output is like this right now:

```
0 Movie(s) in the database. Update, Search, or Quit (U/S/Q): U
Name of the movie: Pulp Fiction
Year: 1994
Rating: 5
Movie Pulp Fiction is added to the database.

1 Movie(s) in the database. Update, Search, or Quit (U/S/Q): U
Name of the movie: Forrest Gump
Year: 1994
Rating: 5
Movie Forrest Gump is added to the database.

1 Movie(s) in the database. Update, Search, or Quit (U/S/Q): S
Name of the movie: Pulp Fiction
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Maybe could you give a try with `gdb`?

Comment: For your information, you edit does nothing useful. Click on "edited <time> ago" and you'll see the complete history!

Comment: You do realize the older revision of your post is still available? If you worry about "plagerism(sic)" (sure it's not embarrasment?), you should delete this question.

Comment: Not embarrassment. Working in university campus lab, fortunately was sitting next to someone who had this question opened copying my solution on this question. Dealt with plagerizer. Reported to professor and was told not to post solutions onto stack overflow.

Comment: Great, so you're a snitch, too.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this code:

```
do
        { 
            current=current->next;
            if (strcmp(searchinput, current->title) == 0)  //PROBLEM LIES HERE
                {show_structure(current);}
        } while(current != NULL);
```

When current is the last element, it is not null.  You enter the top of the loop, set current to current->next, which is null, and then try to access current->title.  But current is NULL.  That is a problem. This would be better:

```
current = first;
while(current != NULL) { 
    if (strcmp(searchinput, current->title) == 0)
        show_structure(current);
    current=current->next;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! A simple switcharoo.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
char maininput[1];
```

and this

```
scanf("%1s", maininput);
```

do not work well with each other.

a %s is a number of characters ending in a \0  so when you write %1s you are expecting at least 2 characters.

instead use `fgetc(stdin)` to read one character from console.